# Do I need cljsbuild plugin if I am just writing clojurescript utility functions?

Tags: compilation, clojurescript

I am a beginner in Clojurescript and I had a doubt. Right now I am simply writing a bunch of utility functions in CLJS files which will be used in other CLJS projects.

So do I still need to compile my CLJS files to JS using cljsbuild plugin? If no, how do I still compile my CLJS source files to check for errors and all?

Answer (score 1):

To get started, I would recommend getting a CLJS REPL running. One option is to use boot cljs. Instruction to set that up here https://github.com/adzerk-oss/boot-cljs-repl

Or, if your functions are simple or pure, and does not have external dependencies, you can try a browser REPL such as http://clojurescript.io No setup required.

Either way, you can just paste the function in the REPL and test them. You will get instant feedback. That should get you started. Later on, you can add testing infrastructures to automate your tests. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

When a ClojureScript project depends on ClojureScript code in a library, it depends on the library's ClojureScript source code directly. (There is no need to compile that library's code to JavaScript for dependency purposes, and in fact, that model is not really supported.)

How does the ClojureScript project depend on the ClojureScript library's code? Typically the library's code is place in a JAR and that JAR is placed on the Java classpath of the project. (Oftentimes such JARs are deployed to Clojars or Maven central.)

A newer, more flexible alternative, using [`deps.edn`](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli) is to have the ClojureScript project depend either on a JAR (as described in the previous paragraph), or to depend directly on the library's local path on disk (using `:local/root`) or the library's GitHub source (using `:git/url` and `:sha`).

To compile and test your code locally you could use [`cljs.main`](https://clojurescript.org/reference/repl-and-main) to load your code in a REPL and exercise it. This can often be as simple as setting up `deps.edn` and then running

```
clj -m cljs.main
```

followed by using `(require my-ns.core)` to load your namespace into the REPL. The [Quick Start](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start) guide is very much worth a read regarding this.

You can use `cljs.main` to run its `cljs.test`-based tests. An example of running test like this using Node is [here](https://clojurescript.org/news/2018-03-26-clojurescript-command-line#running-tests-in-nashorn).

There are other, more sophisticated and feature-rich options out there for compiling and testing ClojureScript library code; the above covers some of the simpler options that ship with ClojureScript itself.